# php size of referenced array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, size

I've got a multidimensional array, which refers to itself multiple times. like:

```
$foo = array(
  0 => array(
    & $foo[1],
    & $foo[2],
    'bar',
  ),
  1 => array(
    & $foo[0],
    & $foo[2],
    'bar',
  ),
  2 => array(
    & $foo[0],
    & $foo[1],
    'bar',
  ),
)
```

Is there a way to get the size (in bites or in amout of elements) of this array?

Kind Regards,

Tempestas Ludi.

Comment: @vusan PHP doesn't mind extra commas at the end of an array.

Comment: It's a fairly straightforward recursive algorithm. What have you tried?

Comment: What is expected size (elements) of this example? 12 (3 main level + 9 from child arrays), 9 (only child arrays), 6 (3 main level + 3 non references from child), 3 (main level only) or 3 (non references from child arrays)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the array, then determine the bytes using: [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

```
$serialized = serialize($foo);
echo mb_strlen($serialized,'8bit');
```